# How to create Dockerfile in command prompt

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Tried to create Dockerfile but not working.I am getting below the error.

Error:

If i tried in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\admin\D1>touch Dockerfile
'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If i tried in VS Code terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\D1> touch Dockerfile
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable    
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and   
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ touch Dockerfile
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `touch` is a linux command, you are on windows, use whatever you want, on powershell you can run `New-Item Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `vi Dockerfile` or `vim Dockerfile`, if it is installed, it may work

Answer (score 0):

It is not something specific to Dockerfile it will be the same if you will create any file. The reason for that is that you are trying a Linux command in the windows command prompt. If you want to use these commands, you need to have a *nix based tool on your windows machine first. In Powershell, I think the equivalent of touch is New-Item.

Comment: How to open Powershell?

Comment: see if this helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7

Comment: Hello, In PowerShell you need to do "New-Item Dockerfile", as I said above if you want to use unix/linux based commands (say touch), you need to install a *nix based tool first and do the operations in that. It all depends with which tool/env you familiar with and i would suggest you go with that.